# Validity of Well formed Fromulas

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How to prove whether this well formed formula is a tautology or not?
∃x,P(x)∧∃x,Q(x)⇒∃x,(P(x)∧Q(x))
So far my approach has been assuming P(x) to be a statement with a truth value(say,"x is odd") and Q(x) to be (say ,"x is even"). But its too confusing for me.
Can anybody suggest a mechanical way of solving this problem(say using truth table)?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your example :
 - $P(x)$ is "$x$ is odd"
 - $Q(x)$ is "$x$ is even"

So, $\exists x, P(x) \land \exists x, Q(x)$ means "There is a $x$ odd, and there is a $x$ even", while $\exists x, P(x)\land Q(x)$ means "There is a $x$ which is both odd and even".

So, the LHS is true while the RHS is false. Thus, the implication is false.

Comment: Now finally I am getting it! thanks so much,for your help. How about this?  ∃x,(P(x)∨Q(x))⇒(~∀x,P(x))∨∃x,Q(x)  .Here LHS is "There is either a x odd ,or a x even" which is true,but I can't figure out the RHS.

Comment: Here, LHS means "There is a $x$ which is either odd, either even" (which is true), and the RHS means "Either it is false that every $x$ is odd, either there is a $x$ which is even" (which is true too, because obviously $\exists x, Q(x)$ is true). This is not a counter-example.

Comment: So just to clarify this statement(in the comment) is valid (tautology) right?  Since T->T is T.

Comment: No. A counter-example is sufficient to show something is false, but an example never shows something is true. To prove your statement, you have to prove it without instantiating $P$ and $Q$, using your favorite deduction system.

Comment: Mr Quinn,can you clarify what you meant by "using your favorite deduction system"?  I am a CS freshman and have beginner level understanding about the topic.So any links,lectures directed towards this topic is highly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for this, I don't think the comments are the right place to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that :

> $∃x P(x) ∧ ∃x Q(x) \to ∃x(P(x)∧Q(x))$

is **not** *valid*, you have to "manufacture" a suitable counter-example.

To prove that e.g.

> $∃x (P(x)∧Q(x)) \to ∃xP(x)∧∃xQ(x)$

is *valid*, you have to argument "semantically" (for simple cases) or derive it with some *proof system*, like [Natural Deduction](http://www.danielclemente.com/logica/dn.en.pdf) or [Tableau Method](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf).